# specify target action to a ember component

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a component that is wrapping content defined by another template. I want an action on the template to trigger a method in my surrounding component. Is this possible?

Here is what I have for my template. Note this is shortened for brevity.

```
{{#drop-down}}
    <div class="menu-selector clickable" {{action "toggleDropdown"}}>
    </div>
{{/drop-down}}
```

This is my component:

```
DropDownComponent = Ember.Component.extend

    showDropdown: false

    actions:
        toggleDropdown: ->
            @toggleProperty 'showDropdown'

`export default DropDownComponent`
```

I can verify that everything else in my component is working. If I put the action in my component that loads this template, it works fine. But that's not where I want it.

Answer (score 0):

So you would like to send an action to **particular** components. Take a notice that

> A component is a custom HTML tag whose behavior you implement using JavaScript and whose appearance you describe using Handlebars templates. They allow you to create **reusable controls** that can simplify your application's templates.

and

> An Ember.Component is a view that is completely isolated.

You are probably using wrong tool here. You should use instead custom view.

```
App.DropdownView = Ember.View.extend
   showDropdown: false
   elemendId: 'dropdown' 

    actions:
        toggleDropdown: ->
            @toggleProperty 'showDropdown'
            return; 

{{#view 'dropdown'}}
<div>
   <div class="menu-selector clickable" {{action "toggleDropdown"}}>
</div>
{{/view}}
```

Then you can send an action to view by

```
Ember.View.views.dropdown.send('toggleDropdown');
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/zoqiluluco/1/